# Creating/Deleting Objects via Checking if Toggles in CheckListBox in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, list, listbox, toggle, checkedlistbox

I am playing around with some CheckedListItems in CheckBoxes and i am having issues with determining when a specific checked Product is checked and/or unchecked via its index  position. 
I know from MsgBox debugging that if i select either Product Allpurpose Cleaner or Cleaning Wipes it calls the MsgBoxes of both methods despite me attempting using logic to only execute for that specific Product. Somehow it thinks I have selected both items?

So essentially i am trying to do this:

If item zero in CheckedListBox is checked
Call conform menu to get desired amountand then come back to ordering menu.
 ElseIF item zero in CheckedListBox is unchecked
Remove it from the current order.

This would essentially be rinse and repeat for all items in my CheckedListBox. I suspect VB.NET is causing my code to 'fall through' and it thinks all of the items i select are the same despite my attempts at preventing this.

May i please have some thoughts on this?

Thank you.

```
Private Sub CleaningProductsList_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CleaningProductsList.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim allPurposeCleaner = New AllPurposeCleaner()
    Dim cleaningCloths = New cleaningCloths()

    ' If checked.
    If CleaningProductsList.GetItemChecked(0) = True Then
        isChecked = True
        Me.Hide()
        ' MsgBox("All Purpose Cleaner Selected")
        AmountMenue.setGivenProduct(allPurposeCleaner)
        AmountMenue.Show()
        ' If unchecked.
    ElseIf CleaningProductsList.GetItemChecked(0) = False Then
        isChecked = False
        ' MsgBox("All Purpose Cleaner  UnSelected ")
        MsgBox(CleaningProductsList.GetItemChecked(0).ToString + " ALLPURPOSE UNCHECKED")
        AmountMenue.removedGivenProduct(allPurposeCleaner)
    End If

    ' If checked.
    If CleaningProductsList.GetItemChecked(1) = True Then
        Me.Hide()
        AmountMenue.setGivenProduct(cleaningCloths)
        MsgBox("cleaning cloths Selected ")
        AmountMenue.Show()
        ' If unchecked.
    ElseIf CleaningProductsList.GetItemChecked(1) = False And CleaningProductsList.CheckOnClick = False Then
        MsgBox("cleaning cloths  UnSelected ")
        MsgBox(CleaningProductsList.GetItemChecked(2).ToString + " Cleaning Cloths UNCHECKED")
        isChecked = False
        AmountMenue.removedGivenProduct(cleaningCloths)
    End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: If `CleaningProductsList` is a `CheckedListBox` then `SelectedIndexChanged` is the wrong event to be handling in the first place. Selection in a `CheckListBox` works exactly the same way as in a regular `ListBox` and has nothing at all to do with checking. If you care about checking then handle an event that relates to checking, i.e. `ItemCheck`. Just be aware that that event is raised BEFORE the change occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you determine changes in a `CheckedListBox`:

```
Private checkedIndexes As New List(Of Integer)
Private checkedItems As New List(Of String)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    CheckedListBox1.Items.AddRange({"First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth"})
End Sub

Private Sub CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.ItemCheck
    If e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked Then
        'An item is being checked.
        checkedIndexes.Add(e.Index)
        checkedItems.Add(CStr(CheckedListBox1.Items(e.Index)))
    Else
        'An item is being unchecked.
        checkedIndexes.Remove(e.Index)
        checkedItems.Remove(CStr(CheckedListBox1.Items(e.Index)))
    End If

    Label1.Text = $"Checked indexes: {String.Join(", ", checkedIndexes)}"
    Label2.Text = $"Checked items: {String.Join(", ", checkedItems)}"
End Sub
```

The `e` parameter tells you what item is changing, via the `Index` property, and what it is changing from and to, via the `CurrentValue` and `NewValue` properties.

If you want to get a full list of checked items in that event handler, because the event is raised before the change is finalised, you need to start with the list provided by the control and then add or remove the current item:

```
Dim checkedItems = CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Cast(Of String)().ToList()

If e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked Then
    checkedItems.Add(CStr(CheckedListBox1.Items(e.Index)))
Else
    checkedItems.Remove(CStr(CheckedListBox1.Items(e.Index)))
End If

'Use checkedItems here.
```